# I made a page loaded with javascript. how can I make a link to the page directly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hyperlink, href

I made many pages to be loaded in div area with javascript.

How can I make a direct link from outside of my website to show the last page?

Thank you so much in advance!

The first javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#content').load('home.php');


    $('a#nav').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('menu/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });

});
```

The second javascript:

```
$('a#navHan').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#contentHan').load('menu/Han/' + page + '.php');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not enirely sure what you mean, but I hope this will help.

You can use hashtags. For example: www.example.com/dir#lastpage.
Then with javascript, you retrieve the hashtag and load the page with jQuery/Ajax.

```
var page = location.hash.substr(1);
$('#content').load("menu/" + page + ".php");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I'm not sure how to use your code. My website is here: http://korean123.tk/index.php . And I want users to go to a page in the menu, for example, Beginner/Hangeul and Pronunciation/Pronunciation Practice. with a link directly from outside.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use hash or query value in the `href` to your page, and use js to read the value when page loading.

---

if hash, for example `www.example.com#google.com`,

```
var page = window.location.hash.substr(1); // page = google.com
```

and change your code into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fullPage = window.location.hash.substr(1); // page = google.com
    if (fullPage == '')
        $('#content').load('home.php');
    else
        $('#content').load(fullPage);


    $('a#nav').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('menu/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });

});
```

the format of your href should be `www.example.com#menu/page_name.php` or `www.example.com#menu/Han/page_name.php`

---

if you use query variables, for example `www.example.com?go=google.com`

```
function getParameterByName(name) { // by jolly.exe at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var page = getParameterByName("go"); // page = google.com
```

and you need to change your code into:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getParameterByName(name) { // by jolly.exe at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    var page = getParameterByName("page");
    var isHan = parseInt(getParameterByName("han")) == 1;
    if (page == '')
        $('#content').load('home.php');
    else
        $('#content').load('menu/' + ((isHan)? "Han/" : "") + page + '.php');


    $('a#nav').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('menu/' + page + '.php');
        return false;
    });

});
```

the format of your href should be `www.example.com?page=page_name` or `www.example.com?page=page_name&han=1`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I'm not sure how to use your code. My website is here: http://korean123.tk/index.php . And I want users to go to a page in the menu, for example, Beginner/Hangeul and Pronunciation/Pronunciation Practice. with a link directly from outside.

Comment: In your page, include my code as $(function(){...})